# Unable to do 'pip install version' with a Python import error - ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'

Tags: python, pip, python3

I am trying to fix an error:

```
import version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'
```

So I tried `pip install version` which gave me the error below:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'
```

So going through different forums, I realized I need to update the file using this import argument `import izip_longest` and update it to `import zip_longest`.

But that file `version.py` seems to be a temporary file and I am unable to access it in Windows 10.

```
C:\TruCalvin\testsfolder>pip install version

Collecting version
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/b6/fa3b2c859d4d8817a106e4272029d78a2afbca0a27139997a4e5515bbf60/version-0.1.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tru~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d5jk1cru\version\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from version import __version__
  File "C:\Users\Tru~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d5jk1cru\version\version.py", line 2, in <module>
    from itertools import izip_longest
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tru~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d5jk1cru\version\
```

How do I mitigate this issue and edit the file so that I can run `pip install version` successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated Setup tools as below >>>  pip install -U setuptools                                   
  but the error remained.                                                                                     
 
     
        from itertools import izip_longest
    ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Tru~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rlj_le73\version\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overiew**

As a rule, `pip` pulls modules from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). The project you are attempting to install is listed there as [version](https://pypi.org/project/version/). So rather than using `pip`, you can simply [download the files](https://pypi.org/project/version/#files) yourself as a compressed `tar.gz` archive using the *Download files* link. In your case, this archive includes `version.py`.

**Installation**

To alter and then install `version.py` in Python 3.x:

- Fully extract `version-0.1.1.tar.gz` (you can use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org) for this on Windows). Note that you will need to go through the process of decompressing the archive *twice* (once for the original `version-0.1.1.tar.gz` file, then once for the remaining `version-0.1.1.tar` file).
- Find `version.py`. Replace `import izip_longest` with `import zip_longest`, as noted in your original question, and then save `version.py`.
- Open a command window in the same folder as `version.py` (*ex.* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *Right-Click* → *Open command window here* — [instructions on enabling this feature in Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/add-open-command-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10)).
- Run e.g. `python setup.py install` to install your altered copy of `version.py`.

**Caveats**

You are likely aware of this, but the reason you are running into the issue with  `import izip_longest` verus `import zip_longest` is because this module is intended for Python 2.x, not Python 3.x. It is also noted on the module page on PyPi that the module itself is (was) in an "Alpha" stage of development. With that in mind, though not guaranteed, you may still run into issues down the road when actually using the module.

Comment: *It worked*  Got till that final step, but That final step was what I was doing wrong earlier. 'python setup.py install',  I was earlier trying to run <python setup.py egg_info> which is obviously not the correct way.  Thank you so much. for your detailed response which helped me here. As you have rightly pointed out, now I have a new error which is a good sign :-) will continue on it.

Comment: Lol well I am glad (???) to hear that. Good luck. =)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for this and there may be things about the `version` package which are worthwhile.

But, chasing this "cannot import name 'izip_longest'" error, I realised that in fact that the PyPi package I really needed (and had used before) was [packaging](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/), not *version*. `packaging` has a module `version` and a class [packaging.version.Version](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/stable/version.html#packaging.version.Version).